# AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth && numberOfLines = 0 doesn't work together as expected

Tags: swift2

```
let nameBox = UILabel(x: 0, y: 0, w: sideSize, h: sideSize*2/4)
nameBox.text = skillName
nameBox.textAlignment = .Center
nameBox.numberOfLines = 0
nameBox.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
nameBox.addBorderLeft(size: 1, color: UIColor.blackColor())
nameBox.addBorderTop(size: 1, color: UIColor.blackColor())
nameBox.addBorderRight(size: 1, color: UIColor.blackColor())
container.addSubview(nameBox)
```

This is the code I have and its output is below.

[image]
[image]

As you can see it has modified everything perfectly except for Communication & Lumberjack. Why is it, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to set the `lineBreakMode` of the label to `.ByWordWrapping`.

Another thought is that you really want the font to be smaller. Perhaps this is prevented by the `minimumScaleFactor` property.

From the docs for `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`:

> The default value for this property is false. If you change it to true, you should also set an appropriate minimum font size by modifying the minimumFontSize property.

*This seems to be a documentation bug. `minimumFontSize` is deprecated.*

Comment: lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping ended up looking like this
http://prntscr.com/at887j
I also tried messing around with; 
baselineAdjustment,
minimumScaleFactor and
allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation

but couldn't find a solution..